# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduceRight')

Tags: react

src/queries.js

```
import { createClient } from "urql"

export const APIURL = "https://api.lens.dev";
export const LENS_HUB_CONTRACT_ADDRESS =
  "0xDb46d1Dc155634FbC732f92E853b10B288AD5a1d";

export const urlClient = createClient({
  url: APIURL,
});

export const queryRecommendedProfiles = `
query RecommendedProfiles {
    recommendedProfiles {
          id
        name
        bio
        attributes {
          displayType
          traitType
          key
          value
        }
          followNftAddress
        metadata
        isDefault
        picture {
          ... on NftImage {
            contractAddress
            tokenId
            uri
            verified
          }
          ... on MediaSet {
            original {
              url
              mimeType
            }
          }
          __typename
        }
        handle
        coverPicture {
          ... on NftImage {
            contractAddress
            tokenId
            uri
            verified
          }
          ... on MediaSet {
            original {
              url
              mimeType
            }
          }
          __typename
        }
        ownedBy
        dispatcher {
          address
          canUseRelay
        }
        stats {
          totalFollowers
          totalFollowing
          totalPosts
          totalComments
          totalMirrors
          totalPublications
          totalCollects
        }
        followModule {
          ... on FeeFollowModuleSettings {
            type
            amount {
              asset {
                symbol
                name
                decimals
                address
              }
              value
            }
            recipient
          }
          ... on ProfileFollowModuleSettings {
           type
          }
          ... on RevertFollowModuleSettings {
           type
          }
        }
    }
  }`;

export const queryExplorePublications = `query ExplorePublications {
    explorePublications(request: {
      sortCriteria: TOP_COMMENTED,
      publicationTypes: [POST, COMMENT, MIRROR],
      limit: 10
    }) {
      items {
        __typename 
        ... on Post {
          ...PostFields
        }
        ... on Comment {
          ...CommentFields
        }
        ... on Mirror {
          ...MirrorFields
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        prev
        next
        totalCount
      }
    }
  }
  
  fragment MediaFields on Media {
    url
    width
    height
    mimeType
  }
  
  fragment ProfileFields on Profile {
    id
    name
    bio
    attributes {
      displayType
      traitType
      key
      value
    }
    isFollowedByMe
    isFollowing(who: null)
    followNftAddress
    metadata
    isDefault
    handle
    picture {
      ... on NftImage {
        contractAddress
        tokenId
        uri
        verified
      }
      ... on MediaSet {
        original {
          ...MediaFields
        }
        small {
          ...MediaFields
        }
        medium {
          ...MediaFields
        }
      }
    }
    coverPicture {
      ... on NftImage {
        contractAddress
        tokenId
        uri
        verified
      }
      ... on MediaSet {
        original {
          ...MediaFields
        }
        small {
         ...MediaFields
        }
        medium {
          ...MediaFields
        }
      }
    }
    ownedBy
    dispatcher {
      address
    }
    stats {
      totalFollowers
      totalFollowing
      totalPosts
      totalComments
      totalMirrors
      totalPublications
      totalCollects
    }
    followModule {
      ...FollowModuleFields
    }
  }
  
  fragment PublicationStatsFields on PublicationStats { 
    totalAmountOfMirrors
    totalAmountOfCollects
    totalAmountOfComments
  }
  
  fragment MetadataOutputFields on MetadataOutput {
    name
    description
    content
    media {
      original {
        ...MediaFields
      }
      small {
        ...MediaFields
      }
      medium {
        ...MediaFields
      }
    }
    attributes {
      displayType
      traitType
      value
    }
  }
  
  fragment Erc20Fields on Erc20 {
    name
    symbol
    decimals
    address
  }
  
  fragment PostFields on Post {
    id
    profile {
      ...ProfileFields
    }
    stats {
      ...PublicationStatsFields
    }
    metadata {
      ...MetadataOutputFields
    }
    createdAt
    collectModule {
      ...CollectModuleFields
    }
    referenceModule {
      ...ReferenceModuleFields
    }
    appId
    hidden
    reaction(request: null)
    mirrors(by: null)
    hasCollectedByMe
  }
  
  fragment MirrorBaseFields on Mirror {
    id
    profile {
      ...ProfileFields
    }
    stats {
      ...PublicationStatsFields
    }
    metadata {
      ...MetadataOutputFields
    }
    createdAt
    collectModule {
      ...CollectModuleFields
    }
    referenceModule {
      ...ReferenceModuleFields
    }
    appId
    hidden
    reaction(request: null)
    hasCollectedByMe
  }
  
  fragment MirrorFields on Mirror {
    ...MirrorBaseFields
    mirrorOf {
     ... on Post {
        ...PostFields          
     }
     ... on Comment {
        ...CommentFields          
     }
    }
  }
  
  fragment CommentBaseFields on Comment {
    id
    profile {
      ...ProfileFields
    }
    stats {
      ...PublicationStatsFields
    }
    metadata {
      ...MetadataOutputFields
    }
    createdAt
    collectModule {
      ...CollectModuleFields
    }
    referenceModule {
      ...ReferenceModuleFields
    }
    appId
    hidden
    reaction(request: null)
    mirrors(by: null)
    hasCollectedByMe
  }
  
  fragment CommentFields on Comment {
    ...CommentBaseFields
    mainPost {
      ... on Post {
        ...PostFields
      }
      ... on Mirror {
        ...MirrorBaseFields
        mirrorOf {
          ... on Post {
             ...PostFields          
          }
          ... on Comment {
             ...CommentMirrorOfFields        
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  fragment CommentMirrorOfFields on Comment {
    ...CommentBaseFields
    mainPost {
      ... on Post {
        ...PostFields
      }
      ... on Mirror {
         ...MirrorBaseFields
      }
    }
  }
  
  fragment FollowModuleFields on FollowModule {
    ... on FeeFollowModuleSettings {
      type
      amount {
        asset {
          name
          symbol
          decimals
          address
        }
        value
      }
      recipient
    }
    ... on ProfileFollowModuleSettings {
      type
      contractAddress
    }
    ... on RevertFollowModuleSettings {
      type
      contractAddress
    }
    ... on UnknownFollowModuleSettings {
      type
      contractAddress
      followModuleReturnData
    }
  }
  
  fragment CollectModuleFields on CollectModule {
    __typename
    ... on FreeCollectModuleSettings {
      type
      followerOnly
      contractAddress
    }
    ... on FeeCollectModuleSettings {
      type
      amount {
        asset {
          ...Erc20Fields
        }
        value
      }
      recipient
      referralFee
    }
    ... on LimitedFeeCollectModuleSettings {
      type
      collectLimit
      amount {
        asset {
          ...Erc20Fields
        }
        value
      }
      recipient
      referralFee
    }
    ... on LimitedTimedFeeCollectModuleSettings {
      type
      collectLimit
      amount {
        asset {
          ...Erc20Fields
        }
        value
      }
      recipient
      referralFee
      endTimestamp
    }
    ... on RevertCollectModuleSettings {
      type
    }
    ... on TimedFeeCollectModuleSettings {
      type
      amount {
        asset {
          ...Erc20Fields
        }
        value
      }
      recipient
      referralFee
      endTimestamp
    }
    ... on UnknownCollectModuleSettings {
      type
      contractAddress
      collectModuleReturnData
    }
  }
  
  fragment ReferenceModuleFields on ReferenceModule {
    ... on FollowOnlyReferenceModuleSettings {
      type
      contractAddress
    }
    ... on UnknownReferenceModuleSettings {
      type
      contractAddress
      referenceModuleReturnData
    }
    ... on DegreesOfSeparationReferenceModuleSettings {
      type
      contractAddress
      commentsRestricted
      mirrorsRestricted
      degreesOfSeparation
    }
  }
  
  `;
```

src/App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  urlClient,
  LENS_HUB_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
  queryRecommendedProfiles,
  queryExplorePublications,
} from "./queries";
import ABI from "./ABI.json";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { Box, Button, Image } from "@chakra-ui/react";

function App() {
  const [account, setAccount] = useState(null);
  const [profiles, setProfiles] = useState([]);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  async function signIn() {
    const accounts = await window.ethereum.requests({
      method: "eth_requestAccounts",
    });
    setAccount(accounts[0]);
  }

  async function getRecommendedProfiles() {
    const response = await urlClient
      .query(queryRecommendedProfiles)
      .toPromise();

    const profiles = response.data.recommendedProfiles.slice(0, 5);
    setProfiles(profiles);
  }

  async function getPosts() {
    const response = await urlClient
      .query(queryExplorePublications)
      .toPromise();

    const posts = response.data.explorePublications.items.filter((post) => {
      if (post.profile) return post;
      return "";
    });
    setPosts(posts);
  }

  async function follow(id) {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(
      LENS_HUB_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
      ABI,
      provider.getSigner()
    );
    const tx = await contract.follow([parseInt(id)], [0x0]);
    await tx.wait();
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getRecommendedProfiles();
    getPosts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Box width="100%" backgroundColor="rgba(5, 32, 64, 28)">
        <Box
          display="flex"
          justifyContent="space-between"
          alignItems="center"
          width="55%"
          margin="auto"
          color="white"
          padding="10px 0"
        >
          <Box>
            <Box fontSize="44px" fontStyle="italic">
              BlockThought
            </Box>
              <Box>Represent your thougths in a textual manner</Box>
          </Box>
          {account ? (
            <Box backgroundColor="000" padding="15px" borderRadius="6px">Connected</Box>
          ) : <Button onClick={signIn} color="rgba(5,32,64)">Connect your wallet</Button>}

        </Box>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

All ways the `reduceRight` is undefined ..
the Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduceRight')
    at compose.ts:25:1
    at Client (client.ts:867:1)
    at ./src/queries.js (queries.js:7:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/App.js (bundle.js:17:66)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76552908

Make sure to replace `ethers.providers` with `EtherscanProvider`
In the current version (v4) you need to pass the exchanges:

https://github.com/urql-graphql/urql/issues/3114#user-content-tsdocs-tsdocs-everywhere-